Please translate the German from song
I wrote a song of sorts with some German many years ago. And now, I wonder what does that Germans says in English? Please help!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djRp51traGg

Wouldn't it be easier to write the lyrics here? The Youtube-link is simply not understandable.

The only thing discernible in this, well, song is

Alles Vergängliche ist nur ein Gleichnis.

repeated multiple times. That's a quote from Faust. Der Tragödie zweiter Teil by Johann Wolfgang von Goethe (you might say, from the sequel to the better known first play). You could translate it to something like

Everything ephemeral is just an allegory.

or, only the eternal (divine) is actually real. As far as any further interpretations go, there are various opinions ;)

Or
Everything transitory is only a parable (nur das Ewige ist wirklich real)

"All of the transient, is parable, only." See https://antilogicalism.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/faust.pdf.
